# App closes automatically when not ran from Xcode

Tags: ios, react-native

I am developing  an app using react native.

When I test it on iOS device connected by USB (when I run from Xcode Integrated development environment). It works as expected. But if I unplug USB cable, the app is still on the phone, can be opened but only displays "NameofTheApp - Powered by React native" and shuts automatically after 10 seconds.

I have following questions

- Is it normal  as it is only on development mode
- Is it a bug which i have to fix before releasing app?

Comment: Your app needs to be connected to the bundler to work in dev. When you unplug your phone your app loses connection to the bundler and ceases to function. If you want it to work when it is on your phone without being plugged in then you need to create a release build. That way the JavaScript bundle is installed on the device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to run the debug version which is unusable after USB debugging because it got disconnected from the server. You need to run it in production mode. Here is [how to do](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

Answer (score 8):

This happened because when you run from the XCode, it has two modes. 
1. **Debug**
2. **Release**

The crash happened because you were running in **release** while running xcode.

While running in Xcode, edit schema and set the mode as debug as follows:

Choose **Product** -> **Scheme** -> **Edit Scheme**. Change the Build Configuration under the Info tab to **debug**.

Comment: I had a similar problem as OP, but with a flutter app. For me this answer basically solved my problem, however I had to do the opposite. I.e. I had been running the app in "debug" and changing it to "release" fixed my problem.

Comment: Same fix worked for me @KB_

Answer (score 0):

For me I had the 'debug executable' checkmark checked.

This is at **Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme**,
Select `Run` section on left side, `info` tab and verify that `debug executable` is Unchecked